# How can I check if someone is using cluster with databricks connect?

Tags: databricks, databricks-connect

When someone is connected to the Databricks cluster , I can see in Clusters details that the certain cluster is active and there are some notebooks attached.
But when I'm using the cluster with **databricks-connect**, cluster is not running.

Is there a way to check if someone is connected to the cluster with databricks-connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that in the Spark UI of the cluster, in the Jobs tab, in the description of the executed job you will see message like: `DB Connect execution from <user-name>`